# Random forest classification using Sentinel 2 data in Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to do RF classification in GEE but i am getting an error

> Classifier (Error) Classifier.train, argument 'classProperty': Invalid
> type. Expected type: String. Actual type: List. Actual value:
> [name, id]

The code which i have entered is as follows:

```
/Loading Sentinel 2 data and filtering by date and bounds
var Sentinel2Collection=ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-01-28')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER', true)
  
    
// Filter the collection by the IMAGE_QUALITY property.
var filtered = Sentinel2Collection
  .filterMetadata('IMAGE_QUALITY', 'equals', 9)
  
var Sentinel_med = Sentinel2Collection.median()
var Sentinel_crop = Sentinel_med.clip(geometry)
    
print(Sentinel_crop)

Map.addLayer(Sentinel_crop, {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], gamma: 2}, 'S2 Image');

//Collecting training data
//Merging the three geometry layers into a single featurecollection
var newfc= forest.merge(urban).merge(agriculture);
print(newfc, 'newfc')

// Select the bands for training
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','B8','B8A'];

// Sample the input imagery to get a FeatureCollection of training data.
var training = Sentinel_crop.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc, 
  properties: ['name','id'], 
  scale: 20
});
print(training, 'training')

// Making a Random Forest classifier and training it.
var classifier= ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: ['name','id'],
  inputProperties: bands
});
print(classifier)

//Classifying the input imagery
var classification= Sentinel_crop.select(bands).classify(classifier)

// Define a palette for the Land Use classification.
var palette = [
  'D3D3D3', // forest (0)  // red
  '0000FF', // urban (1)  // green
  '008000' //  agriculture (2) // blue
];
print(classification)
// Display the classification result and the input image.
Map.addLayer(classification, {min: 0, max: 2, palette: palette}, 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

In training the classifier, you provided a list of `['name', and 'id']`. From the docs:

> classProperty (String):
> The name of the property containing the class value. Each feature must have this
> property, and its value must be numeric.

You must provide a string as input. I am unable to run your code due to not having access to the `forest` featurecollection, but assuming that the `name` property encodes the label for each of your features, this should work:

```
// Making a Random Forest classifier and training it.
var classifier= ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'name',
  inputProperties: bands
});
```